# What is going on with my for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm having a really confusing time operating the following loop:

```
int indexPos;
    for(indexPos = 0; indexPos < size; indexPos++) {
        System.out.println(indexPos + "!");
        if(sourceModuleValue < controlPoints.get(indexPos).inputValue) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indexPos + "?");
```

I added in the `println`s so I could see why I was getting errors. Some other things to note: In my program, `size = 7` and `controlPoints` is an `ArrayList`, but I don't think that's what's causing my problems. Here's the readout:

```
0!
1!
2!
3!
3?
0!
1!
2!
2?
0!
1!
2!
3!
4!
5!
6!
6?
0!
1!
1?
0!
1!
1?
0!
1!
2!
3!
4!
5!
6!
6?
0!
1!
2!
3!
4!
4?
0!
1!
1?
0!
1!
1?
0!
1!
2!
2?
0!
1!
2!
3!
4!
5!
6!
7?
```

To my knowledge, this loop should *never* output a value of `indexPos` greater than `6`, since I thought that's how `for` loops worked. `controlPoints` can `get` the value inside the loop, but after the `break`, the number is incremented again. I thought the number doesn't increment until the end of the loop? Is this wrong? Should I be incorporating a pre-increment instead of a post-increment?

Comment: Could you post `size`, `sourceModuleValue ` and `controlPoints` values?

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal example.

Comment: Whenever you encounter situations like these it is best to just plop a breakpoint right at the start of the loop and go through a few iterations. DO THAT, and try to figure it out :)

Comment: If the `if` condition is never satisfied during the loop the final result will be 7 since that's how your loop conditions are defined.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, I just realized this too, guess I should've thought about it a little more before posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `for` loop goes to the end, the value of `indexPos` is the upper bound

```
for(indexPos = 0; indexPos < size; indexPos++)
```

The last time `for` executes, `indexPos` is increased. Since it does not meet the `indexPos < size` condition, the loop is not executed

Which explains that if no `break` has been called within the `for` loop, the value of `indexPos` is a value not possible within the `for` loop, here equals to `size`, i.e 7

(this is the same behaviour as in C, since this construct is inherited from C language)

Comment: Yeah, that's it, I just figured out the one time it didn't work was when the if-statement never returned true. I'll accept your answer when stack overflow lets me